# File not open for writing in Python script

Tags: python

My script is not working, I can't figure out where the bug is, I have opened the file with the **open()** function each time I want to work with the file in **Python**, and when running it signals this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_example.py", line 26, in <module>
    doc.truncate()
IOError: File not open for writing
```

To run it I run it this way in the Terminal:

```
python my_example.py my_example_sample.txt
```

Here's the **Python** Script (code) :

```
from sys import argv
#from os.path import exists

script, filename = argv

print "The name of this program is %s" % script
print "The name of the file you want to read is %s" % filename
print "Press ENTER if you want to read the selected document."
print "Press CTRL-C to cancel."

raw_input('>')

print "%s :" % filename

doc = open(filename)

print doc.read()

#doc.close()

erase_file = raw_input("Do you want to erase the file %s Y/N? : " % filename)

if erase_file == "Y":
    doc = open(filename)
    print "Truncating the file..."
    doc.truncate()
    print "Done, truncated."
    #doc.close()
else:
    print "That's okay!"

write_file = raw_input("Do you want to write in the file %s Y/N? : " % filename) 
if write_file == "Y":
    doc = open(filename)
    print "I'm going to ask you to type in what you like to write in the file %s 
    (limited to 3 lines)" % filename
    line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
    line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
    line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")
    print "Perfect! writing in..."
    doc.write(line1)
    doc.write('\n')
    doc.write(line2)
    doc.write('\n')
    doc.write(line3)
    doc.write('\n')
    print "Done!"
    doc.close()
else:
    print "Ok, see you later!"
    doc.close()
# add copy and exists? features?
```

Any solution?

What the program does is simply reading (**read()**) a file *(printing the file)*, ask the user if he wants to erase the file (**truncate()**) and if he wants to write in it (**write()**) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, [`open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) opens for *reading*. If you want to open for writing, you have to pass the second argument of open as well to specific the mode (e.g. `'w'` for writing).

Comment: That worked, now the script runs perfectly, just one more thing, when do I really need to **close()** the **open()** files? For example, where I wrote the comment _#doc.close()_ I wrote it in order to close the file after printing it out with **print doc.read()** , should I close all the opened files immediately after working with them? or can I just close the files at the end of the program if maybe I'm going to work with them again (depending on the IF statements), as my program shows .

Comment: Python will automatically close all open files when it finishes the script; alternatively you can use the `with` construct to end them when the with-block ends to avoid having them open for extended periods of time in longer scripts. You'll definitely want to close a file before you re-open it in a different mode.